# ¿Por qué al subir mi sitio a un hosting, no se detectan los fonts?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-fonts

De forma local los fonts trabajan sin problema, pero al subirlo a un hosting, estas no son detectadas. Ya verifiqué las rutas e intenté con otros navegadores.

```
    <!-- Google fonts -->
     <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen:400,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Qwigley" >
    <!-- Font awesome -->
     <link href="font-awesome-4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pueden ser cuestiones del protocolo `http` o `https`, podrías cambiar tu url a `https`:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen:400,300" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

O intentar usar la url sin ello:

```
<link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen:400,300" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

También te recomendaría intentar traer las fuentes con un `@import` en un `<style>`

```
<style>
  @import url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen:400,300');
</style>
```

Comment: gracias por tu aporte, pero de ninguna de las dos formas lo conseguí. Abrí el sitio en una sesión en incognito pero tampoco.

Comment: Y si intentas cambiar el http de tus rutas por https?

Comment: @ Levi Arista No, sólo se lo había quitado, PERO AGREGANDO EL PROTOCOLO https funcionó! Gracias!!!

Comment: Genial, modificaré la respuesta para aclarar eso y le sirva a alguien más

Comment: @ Levi Arista Gracias Crack!!!